# I'm trying to next statements using sql select & vb .net

Tags: sql, vb.net, subquery

I've done something like this in pvp using while loop but I don't think that is valid for vb. I have a total of 4 tables and 3 of them are based off of 1.

```
Main Table:
weather

Sub Tables:
applicationData
accidentData
trafficData
```

My goal is to use my filter system to check the weather data table. It then searches the other tables for traffic, accident, and application data based off  the location, date, and time of the weather data fields. (They all share these columns). There are times where there are several accidents for each date/time/location.

For the sake of being easier to explain I'd like you to explain it with two different tables so here are my queries.

```
SELECT event, date, time, location 
FROM weather 
WHERE date= '" & datepicker.Text & "' 
AND time = '" & eventTime.SelectedItem.Value & "'
```

I then want to take the date, time, and location and search one of the sub tables with that information.

```
SELECT roadway_number, mile_marker 
FROM  accident 
WHERE date= 'query1Date' 
AND time = 'query1Time' 
AND location = 'query1Location'
```

I think want to display all this information in a datagrid and have it display to show all weather fields even if there is no accident data to go with it. Like this:

1pm, 12/1/10, Amity
Weather Event: Snow

2pm, 12/1/10, Amity
Weather Event: Light Rain

5pm, 12/1/10 Amity
Weather Event: Heavy Snow
Accident:
Road: I165N, Mile_Marker 95.5
Road: I165N, Mile_Marker 71

7pm, 12/1/10 Amity
Weather Event: Heavy Snow
Accident:
Road: I165S, Mile_Marker 85.5

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection. Not cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying the database in a loop (a real performance killer), join the tables in your query:

```
SELECT weather.event, weather.date, weather.time, location,
    accident.roadway_number, accident.mile_marker
FROM weather
LEFT OUTER JOIN accident on weather.date = accident.date and weather.time = accident.time
    and weather.location = accident.location
WHERE date= '" & datepicker.Text & "' AND time = '" & eventTime.SelectedItem.Value & "'
```

The OUTER join is the key to getting all weather records regardless of if there are related accidents.

You should also look into parametrizing your query instead of concatenating the input values.

Comment: I attempted to use this for my application data (location is actually called tmc)

SELECT weather.event, weather.date, weather.time, weather.tmc, application.weather, application.surface_temperature FROM weather LEFT OUTER JOIN application on weather.date = application.date and weather.time = application.time and weather.tmc = application.tmc WHERE weather.date= '" & datepicker.Text & "'

I display it with a datalist

event and weather time show up, but the application data doesn't (No Error)

Comment: I figured out what my issue is. my csv file put breaks at the end of my cells so it snot finding exact matches.... I did "like" with % and it worked.. Gotta fixed my csv -> mysql conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an left outer join for this:

```
SELECT w.event, w.date, w.time, w.location, a.roadway_number, a.mile_marker 
FROM weather w
LEFT OUTER JOIN accident a ON a.date = w.date 
                          AND a.time = w.time
                          AND a.location = w.location
WHERE w.date= '" & datepicker.Text & "' 
AND w.time = '" & eventTime.SelectedItem.Value & "'
```

Comment: I Had the same issue with this as I did with the persons response after you. the weather table data shows but the accident does not.

I'm using a datalist and

<li>Time: <%#Container.DataItem("Time")%>, Event: <%#Container.DataItem("Event")%><br />
                    Weather: <%#Container.DataItem("mile_marker")%>, Surface Temperature: <%#Container.DataItem("roadway_number")%></li>

I tried using a.roadway_number but I get an error when i do this

Comment: I figured out what my issue is. my csv file put breaks at the end of my cells so it snot finding exact matches.... I did "like" with % and it worked.. Gotta fixed my csv -> mysql conversion. Thanks!